# Example for using developers authentication(aws cognito) for android app

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have been struggling to understand how AWS Cognito should be implemented in java for android App user Authentication. I have seen Github codes for android but code is difficult for me to understand as I am beginner to android. Can anybody explain it with simple code? Specially how the user calls backendserver in java to get the ID.Any Simple explaination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea is that you will have an authentication server (backend) which will be the sole authority to verify user credentials. The high level flow will be:

1. The end user will provide credentials(username and password) on your Android App.
2. Android App will call your backend to verify the credentials.
3. Backend will call [GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity.html) API of Amazon Cognito for that end-user (using the username)
4. Cognito will return an identityId associated with that username and a OpenId Connect Token to your backend and it will passed back to the Android App.
5. Cognito SDK will use this token to call Amazon STS to get AWS credentials for the end user.

I would highly encourage you to follow our [blog post](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3E3NJURV1LNV1/Integrating-Amazon-Cognito-using-developer-authenticated-identities-An-end-to-en) and the [developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/developer-authenticated-identities/), it explains this flow in depth. As always, if you have any questions please feel free to ask.

Thanks.

Comment: Backend will call GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity API of Amazon Cognito for that end-user (using the username). Does this mean do I need to provide the username to AWS cognito before hand? Does not it become a problem for developer to feed all the usernames to AWS Cognito? Is there a way to register users themselves to Cognito while registering App programatically?

Comment: No, you do not have to provide the usernames to Amazon Cognito before hand. There is no registration of users. Basically when you provide a username, Cognito returns you an identityId. The next time you pass this username again, you will get the dame identityId.

Currently Amazon Cognito does not support registering usernames. We have heard this request from other customers and will consider it in future updates to the service.